# Send RSA Object with ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, rsa, objectoutputstream

I try to send with ObjectOutpuStream this RSA custom Object that I have done Serializable. Why ObjectInputStream receives a null pointer and throw exception NullPointer because  No class founded

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAKeyGenParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public class NewRSA implements Serializable{

   private KeyPair keys ;


   public NewRSA(){
       this.keys=null;
   }
   public NewRSA(KeyPair keys)
   {
       this.keys=keys;
   }
    public KeyPair getKPair()
    {
        return keys;
    }
     public void setKPair(KeyPair keys)
    {
        this.keys=keys;
    }
  public  KeyPair generateRsaKeyPair(int keySize, BigInteger publicExponent)
  {

    try
    {
      KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      RSAKeyGenParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(keySize, publicExponent);
      keyGen.initialize(spec);
      keys = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    return keys;
  }



    public  byte[] rsaEncrypt(byte[] original, PublicKey key) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, BadPaddingException
  {


      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
      return cipher.doFinal(original);



  }


  public static byte[] rsaDecrypt(byte[] encrypted, PrivateKey key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
  {

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
      return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);


  }
}
```

Error is:
No classe

Output PrintStackTrace
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPrivateCrtKey
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at stefano.Server$ServerThread.attemptLog(Server.java:268)
    at stefano.Server$ServerThread.handshake(Server.java:402)
    at stefano.Server$ServerThread.run(Server.java:428)

Comment: _"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPrivateCrtKey"_, this is btw not a `NullPointerException`

Comment: you should download the project platform_external_conscrypt that contains this class

Comment: Yes, you're right. How can I solve it, please show me an example, because I wrote a java server that receives an object from android client

Comment: serialized classes are not necessarily portable, and certainly going from Android to Oracle Java is likely to break.

Comment: I am also facing same issue did u find the solution ?

Comment: I don't find a solution yet. I update it when I face that problem again

Answer (score 0):

`Serializable` classes can't really be converted from the Android JVM to the usual Oracle/OpenJDK JVM, you can use the `Externalizable` interface to manually serialize your class and retrieve it on the backend. There is however a solution that might work, it's to write your backend API in an IDE (using the Oracle Java) and compile it. It might work because the class signatures and headers are the same (it's a 50/50 Chance).